# Maven Dependency Plugin: Incorrect analysis for dependencies in tests?

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using `maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:analyze-only` to control my dependencies. We have a corporate-wide parent POM that defines the possible dependencies in `dependencyManagement` and there are dependencies in every Maven scope.

Also, I configured `<outputXML>` to be `true` on the plugin, because it's very handy to just copy/paste the missing dependencies from the plugin's report to the POM.

So, we have a `util-foobar` project for general utility classes (scope `compile`) and a `util-baz-test` for utility classes that are only used for testing (scope `test`).

Now, if I use a class from `util-foobar` in my main source, everything's ok and the dependency analysis is correct. And the same goes for using `util-baz-text` in my test source.

However, if I use a class from `util-foobar` **only** in my test source, the plugin will show me the dependencies missing, due to `<outputXML>`. And it will tell me that I need to add `util-foobar` with scope `compile` instead of scope `test`. It looks like the plugin is only considering the scopes from dependency management and not looking at where in the source folders the class requiring `util-foobar` is located.

Am I doing something wrong or is the plugin working as designed?